# reactjs - this.props not defined outside constructor

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which I have passed a property from another component.

As following `<RegisterVisitor someProperty={this.aFunction} />`

In the child component however `this.props` is undefined outside of the constructor.

I took out the snippet of the code. `this.props` is defined in `render ()` but it is not defined `registerVisitor`. Anyone know what the problem could be?

```
export default class RegisterVisitor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.registerVisitor = this.registerVisitor.bind(this);
    }

    registerVisitor () {            
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/visit',
            type: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
        .done(
            function(result) {
                this.props.someProperty; //<------  undefined
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `.done` callback `this` does not refer to `RegisterVisitor`, you should set `this` for callback., you can do it with [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
...
.done(
  function(result) {
     this.props.someProperty;
  }.bind(this)
);
```

or also you can use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
...
.done((result) => {
  this.props.someProperty;
});
```

Comment: @Alexander thanks solved my problem, and now off for some well earned weekend xD